# When can colour charge indices be equated?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, color-charge

I'm currently studying QFT and QCD for the first time and I have a question about the colour charge indices given below. I was asked the following question:

> (a) Derive the Feynman rule for the 3-gluon vertex $V\left[A_{\mu_1}^{a_1}\left(p_1\right), A_{\mu_2}^{a_2}\left(p_2\right), A_{\mu_3}^{a_3}\left(p_3\right)\right]$ from
> $$
> \mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{QCD}}=-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu}^a F^{a, \mu \nu}+\ldots, \quad F_{\mu \nu}^a=\partial_\mu A_\nu^a-\partial_\nu A_\mu^a-g_{\mathrm{s}} f^{a b c} A_\mu^b A_\nu^c.
> $$

I was given the correct working but I'm confused about the below section of it, specifically how the colour indices d and e seem to become b and c when collecting the terms. I'm sure it's probably straightforward and I'm missing something obvious but any help would be appreciated.

$$
\begin{aligned}
& i L_{Q C D}=-\frac{i}{4} F_{\mu v}^a F^{a, \mu v}+\ldots \\
& =-\frac{i}{4}\left(\partial_\mu A_\nu^a-\partial_\nu A_\mu^a-g_s f^{a b c} A_\mu^b A_\nu^c\right)\left(\partial^\mu A^{a, \nu}-\partial^v A^{a, \mu}-g_s f^{a d e} A^{d, \mu} A^{e, v}\right) \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

Collecting terms with AAA:
$$
\begin{aligned}
i L_{Q C D}= & -i\left(\partial_\mu A_\nu^a-\partial_\nu A_\mu^a\right)\left(-g_s f^{a d e} A^{d, \mu} A^{e, \nu}\right) \\
& -\frac{i}{4}\left(-g_s f^{a b c} A_\mu^b A_v^c\right)\left(\partial^\mu A^{a, v}-\partial^v A^{a, \mu}\right)+\ldots \\
= & \frac{i g_s}{2}\left(\partial_\mu A_v^a-\partial_v A_\mu^a\right) f^{a b c} A^{b, \mu} A^{c, v}+\ldots
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Since $X^{abcbc}=X^{dede}$, $X^{abcbc}+X^{adede}=2X^{abcbc}$. (I'm taking $X^{afghi}:=f^{afg}A^{h,\,\mu}A^{i,\,\nu}$, hiding Greek indices.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since d and e are being summed over (and it’s not multiplying other terms with b and c indices which could cause semantic issues), it’s valid to rename them as b and c.

Comment: Ah it's a dummy index thing then. Is it convention in QFT that two identical indices imply summation even when they're both upper? I'm just used to upper/lower summation.

Comment: @Aidan Yes, this implies summation.